# How to load this sql dataset to mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a dataset from Datacamp to my MySQL workbench software on my laptop.

https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/1069/datasets/578834f5908e3b2fa575429a287586d1eaeb2e54/countries2.zip

There is a file called countries.sql and also various csv files for different tables. 
I tried to import the "countries.sql" file but get some errors as seen in the attachment.
I will appreciate your helps on this.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: We can do nothing with an image of the code. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Please [edit] your question to include the SQL and the text of the error message as text here in your post. .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shoul define varchars length, replace all `varchar` to `varchar(200)`

Comment: yes, the errors indeed disappeared after I replaced varchar to varchar(200).Thanks for this. But this time I get an error message 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. I only have countries.sql and csv files ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to create database, where you will save that data, if you already did, then add first line `use database`, where database is your database name

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. So I can't use this dataset by itself on MySQL as far as I understand right? I have only countries.sql and different csv files, such as countries, currencies etc